# Is it possible to bind one solution to more than one TFS servers?

Tags: tfs

We're doing a wide range of products for customers, and they ask for the source code too.

Because of some policies, we need to develop solutions in our company's TFS and once in a while commit our code to the customer's TFS too.

And because of that, it's really getting hard and annoying always copying and duplicating data to another folder for that purpose.

Is there a way to bind one solution to two TFS servers?

Comment: You use TFVC or Git version control in TFS?

Comment: I'm using TFVC.

Comment: TFVC is not support to bind one solution to 2 different TFS server. I suggest you to use Git version control. You could follow these documents ([1](https://www.visualstudio.com/learn/migrate-from-tfvc-to-git/), [2](https://www.concurrency.com/blog/may-2016/converting-tfvc-to-git))you to learn about move from TFVC to Git.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

My suggestion is to use a tool/script to remove the bindings before committing to your customer repository. There are many of these like [Unbind](http://blog.accentient.com/removing-tfs-bindings-from-solutions-and-projects/) or [ExportSrc](https://exportsrc.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you use TFVC version control, it is impossible to bing your solution with 2 TFS verion control.

If you use Git version control, it is possible. You could add more than one remote server for your local git repository. A local Git repo could have more than one remote server(both TFS and Github could be a remote), using `git remote add [remote name] [tfs repository url]` command to add a remote. Using `git remote -v` to list all remotes.

When you push/fetch, using `git push [remote name]` to sync code with different remotes

Reference:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

https://mmikowski.github.io/git-cross-origin/

**Update:**

I suggest you to use Git version control. You could follow these documents you to learn about move from TFVC to Git.

[migrate from tfvc to Git](https://www.visualstudio.com/learn/migrate-from-tfvc-to-git/)

[Converting a TFVC Repository to Git](https://www.concurrency.com/blog/may-2016/converting-tfvc-to-git)